# Difference between Readonly<[]> and ReadOnlyArray<>

Tags: typescript, readonly

**Code 1:**

```
let readonlyArray: ReadonlyArray<string | number> = ["test", 1, 1];
```

**Code 2:**

```
let readonlyArray: Readonly<[string, number]> = ["test", 1, 1];
```

Both lines of code seem to do similar things. I don't know what is the difference between declaring array as `ReadOnly` and `ReadOnlyArray`.

Also, which one is  best for performance and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From a performance point of view, there should not be any difference between the two, as types are erased at runtime and the same javascript will run regardless

There is a fundamental difference between the two types at compile time:

`Readonly<T>` - Is a type that has the same shape as `T` but all the properties are read-only. In your case the `T` is the tuple type  `[string, number]`, so it will have all the properties of array as well as the indexes 0 and 1. So we can call the `push` method, but we can't reassign the `concat` method.

```
let readonlyArray: Readonly<[string, number]> = ["test", 1, 1];
readonlyArray.concat = ()=> {} // Not valid, concat is readonly 
readonlyArray.push(1); // This is valid 
readonlyArray[1] =  ""; // Invalid we cannot change a property by indexing 
readonlyArray[3] =  ""; // Valid as it was not in the original tuple type
```

**Edit**: Since 3.4, typescript has changed the behavior of mapped types on array and tuples, so `Readonly<[string, number]>` is now equivalent to a readonly tuple `readonly [string, number]`, so the errors are a bit different:

```
let readonlyArray: Readonly<[string, number]> = ["test", 1];
readonlyArray.concat = ()=> {} // Not valid, concat is readonly 
readonlyArray.push(1); // This is not valid, no push method anymore
readonlyArray[1] =  ""; // Invalid we cannot change a property by indexing 
readonlyArray[3] =  ""; // Invalid now tuple length preserved
```

**</Edit>**

`ReadonlyArray<T>` is a true readonly array that does not have any methods that can change the array. In your case any item of the array can be either a `string` or a `number`:

```
let readonlyArray2: ReadonlyArray<string | number> = ["test", 1, 1];
readonlyArray2.concat = ()=> []; // Valid we can set the concat property on the object 
readonlyArray2.push(1) // No push method, invalid
readonlyArray2[1] =  ""; // Invalid it is read only 
readonlyArray2[3] =  ""; // Invalid it is read only
```

Answer (score 2):

### Readonly

- The `Readonly<T>` is not necessarily an array; that expects any type `<T>`
- To make the `Readonly` to store an array of values, the type `<T>` should be an `[T]`
- Does not contain mutable methods

  ```
  let readonlyArray: Readonly<string| number> = ["test", 1, 1];    // not assignable

  let readonlyArray: Readonly<[string| number]> = ["test", 1, 1]; // assignable
  ```

### ReadonlyArray

- The `ReadonlyArray` accepts by default an array
- Contains mutable methods

  ```
  let readonlyArray: ReadonlyArray<string| number> = "test";      // not assignable

  let readonlyArray: ReadonlyArray<string| number> = ["test"];   // assignable
  ```

Comment: Sorry. I think you  missunderstand the question. I am  not asking the difference and performance about `Readonly` and `ReadOnlyArray`.  I want to know the difference and performance about `declared array as read-only` and `read-only array`.

Comment: Actually `let readonlyArray: Readonly<string| number> = ["test", 1, 1];` is assignable. You can generally assign a tuple with more elements to a tuple with less elements

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir but you are trying to assign a array which is not possible you will get the error `Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.`